# problem with onmouseout for my javascript custom select

Tags: javascript, select, html-lists, onmouseout

I've created a custom select using javascript as described here: http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/

The key idea is that the select is built of a  containing two (in my case)

s.  What I want to do is add an onmouseover function that should read something like:

```
ulNode.onmouseout = function() {
      if (ulNode.className.indexOf('selectOpen') !- -1){
         selectMe(li[0]);
      }
}
```

i.e. if the mouse leaves the ul, and the ul is open, the first element should be selected.  This works fine, *but* this function gets called when I move my mouse between li's, even though I haven't left the containing ul.  Any ideas why that might happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mouseover` and `mouseout` are wrong king of events for this case. They are fired way too often when you have other elements inside the element that has mouseout event. You need something like `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`

[Mouseleave in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Comment: boom!  thankyou.  interesting that mouseout get's fired so much - is this behaviour ever useful?

Comment: Not really. It's very annoying

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing some delay before the mouseout event like this:

```
var hover_to = null;
$("ul").mouseover(function() {
   window.clearTimeout(hover_to);
   // (A) your stuff...
}).mouseout(function() {
   hover_to = window.setTimeout(function() {
      // (B) your stuff...
   },200);
});
```

This hopefully handles the nonwanted atomic events. 
Careful with the scope in `(B)`.